# Reboot Java Application with Linux

Tags: java, linux, centos

What would be a solution to rebooting a java application with linux instead of using

"sh run.sh"

in terminal whenever I want to reboot it? The run.sh contains this:

```
    java -Xmx1024m -Xss2m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+UseParallelGC -classpath bin:data/libs/* com.runeown.Application
```

I want to restart it using terminal.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the shell script? You can deploy the script with your application and create a desktop shortcut that runs the script (see http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/ or http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).

Comment: How do you want to restart it? From a web page? Automatically when it uses too many resources? Currently your question sounds like you want to restart it, just not using a .sh file.

Comment: Just do `chmod a+rx run.sh`, put the `run.sh` in your `PATH` and type simply `run.sh`

Comment: I want to restart it because it is a game application. It will only be restarted when I update it, and instead of going over to my terminal, restarting it without doing that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to restart it using "sh run.sh" and instead you want to restart it using a command, you could use a bash alias to run the command.

here is the manual (http://www.ss64.com/bash/alias.html)

here is a relevant askubuntu thread about making a permanent alias (https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

An alias is essentially a shortcut for the terminal, for instance you had a dropbox folder located at ~/myfiles/1/2/dropbox and you did not want to type cd + path every time, you could make an alias:

alias cddropbox="cd ~/myfiles/1/2/dropbox"